# How can I get the members of a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

It is my code Python :

```
my_dict = {
    'Iran':[win_iran,loss_iran,draw_iran,diff_iran,point_iran],
    'Morocco':[win_marakesh,loss_marakesh,draw_marakesh,diff_marakesh,point_marakesh],
    'Portugal':[win_por,loss_por,draw_por,diff_por,point_por],
    'Spain':[win_spain,loss_spain,draw_spain,diff_spain,point_spain]}
```

I want to have this output:

```
Spain  wins: , loses: , draws: , goal difference: , points:
Iran  wins:1 , loses: , draws: , goal difference: , points:
Portugal  wins: , loses: , draws: , goal difference: , points:
Morocco  wins: , loses: , draws: , goal difference: , points:
```

please guide me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What have you already tried, and what do you need help with exactly? It's hard for us to help with this code because all those names are undefined, starting with `win_iran`. And for the output, it seems like you want to fill in numbers for all those slots, right? So what should the actual output look like given some example input data? See [mre]. You can [edit] to clarify.

Comment: BTW, having a separate name for each number for each country is more complicated than necessary, but it's not clear how to improve it without seeing how they're defined.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward:

```
for key,val in my_dict.items():
    print(f"{key}: wins:{val[0]}, losses:{val[1]}, draws:{val[2]}, goal difference:{val[3]}, points:{val[4]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the `dict`'s items, unpacking to useful names, then `print` the values as needed:

```
for country, (wins, losses, draws, diff, points) in my_dict.items():
    print(f'{country} wins: {wins}, losses: {losses}, draws: {draws}, '
          f'goal difference: {diff}, points: {points}')
```

Or less explicitly, but more succinctly, use `str.format` and use star-unpacking with implicit numbering so you don't repeat names as much:

```
for country, stats in my_dict.items():
    print(('{} wins: {}, losses: {}, draws: {}, goal difference: {}, '
           'points: {}').format(country, *stats))
```